# One composite index or many indexes for foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql

Whats is the difference between creating a covering index for all the foreign keys of a relation table and creating one index for each column (foreign key) of the relation table ?

For instance, I have the table `sales(p_id, e_id, c_id, ammount)` where p_id is a foreign key (products table), e_id is a foreign key (employee table) and c_id a foreign key (customer_table). The primary key of the table is `{p_id, e_id, c_id}`.
Which on is better ?

```
CREATE INDEX cmpindex ON sales(p_id, e_id, c_id)
```

OR

```
CREATE INDEX pindex on sales(p_id)
CREATE INDEX eindex on sales(e_id)
CREATE INDEX cindex on sales(c_id)
```

I mostly run queries with joins on the relation table and the parent tables.

Comment: If the primary key is `p_id, e_id, c_id`, you already have a covering index. A PK *is* an index.

Comment: It depends on your purpose to use (those) indexes. First search about how index work, then you would have your answer yourself. And your `PK` already implicitly create your first index.

Comment: I mostly run queries with joins on the relation table and the parent tables.

Comment: MySQL has pretty good documentation on multi-column indexes:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which one is better depends on your actual queries.

One thing to understand is that when you join the table `sales` once in your query, it will only use one index for it (at the most). So you need to make sure an index is available that is most appropriate for the query.

If you join the `sales` table always to all three other tables (`customer`, `product` and `employee`) then a composite index is to be preferred, assuming that the engine will actually use it and not perform a table scan.

The order of the fields in the composite index is important when it comes to the order of the results. For instance, if your query is going to group the results by product (first), and then order the details per customer, you could benefit from an index that has the product id first, and the customer id as second.

But it may also be that the engine decides that it is better to start scanning the table `sales` first and then join in the other three tables using their respective primary key indexes. In that case no index is used that exists on the `sales` table.

The only way to find out is to get the execution plan of your query and see which indexes will be used when they are defined.

If you only have one query on the `sales` table, there is no need to have several indexes. But more likely you have several queries which output completely different results, with different field selections, filters, groupings, ...Etc.

In that case you may need several indexes, some of which will serve for one type of query, and others for others. Note that what you propose is not mutually exclusive. You could maybe benefit from several composite indexes, which just have a different order of fields.

Obviously, a multitude of indexes will slow down data changes in those tables, so you need to consider that trade-off as well.

Answer (score 1):

Note that an index on a compound key will only be used if you query on the first portion, the first and second portion, the first, second and third portion, etc., so querying on p_id or p_id and e_id, etc. or even e_id and p_id will utilize the index. Indeed, any query containing p_id will use this index. 
However, if you query your Sales table on e_id or c-id or any combination of these two, cmpindex will not be used and a full table scan will be performed.

One benefit of having an index on each foreign key (a non-unique index, as there could be multiple sales of the same product, or by the same employee, or to the same customer, leading to duplicate entries in the index) is that the query optimizer has the option of using the index to reduce the number of rows returned, and then doing a sequential search through the result set.

E.g. if the query is a search on sales of a particular product to a particular customer (regardless of employee) and you have a million sales, the foreign key index cindex could be used to return 20 sales items to that particular customer, and that result set could be very efficiently searched sequentially to find which of these sales were for a particular product. 
If the search was performed on Product and pindex was used, the result set may be 10,000 rows (all sales of that product), which would have to be sequentially searched to find the sales of that product to a particular customer, leading to a very inefficient query.

I believe that the statistics kept for a table (used by the optimizer) keep track of the average number of rows that will be returned for a query using each index, so the optimizer will be able to work out that cindex should be used rather than pindex in the examples above. Alternatively, you can give hints on your queries to specify that a particular index be used. 
It is, obviously, important to run UPDATE STATISTICS on a regular basis, as the execution plan would use pindex in the example above if there were, on average, only 10 sales of each product.

Answer (score 0):

If your queries(search) propagates through sales for each of tables independently then you must create a separate index for each.
If that's not necessary then you can go for composite.

Answer (score 0):

As HoneyBadger commented, you already have a composite index, since your primary key is itself an index.

In general, you should use a single index for each column whenever you think you will have queries involving each field by itself.

As stated [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), when you have a composite index, it can work with queries involving all fields, or with queries involving the first field (in order), the first and the second, or the first,second and third together. It won't be used in queries involving only the second and third field.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are missing an important point.  When you declare a foreign key in MySQL, it creates an index on the column.  This is not (necessarily) true in other databases, but it is true in MySQL.

So, the declaration automatically creates these indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX pindex on sales(p_id);
CREATE INDEX eindex on sales(e_id);
CREATE INDEX cindex on sales(c_id);
```

(These indexes are very handy for dealing with cascading constraints and maintaining the data integrity based on the foreign key.)

If you happen to have also declared an index on `sales(p_id, e_id, c_id, amount)`, then the first of the indexes is not needed -- it is a subset of this index.  However, the other two are needed.

Is this index needed?  As mentioned in other questions, that depends on the queries you want to use the index for.  I recommend starting with the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on this subject to understand how the indexes get used.